# limit of two variables

Tags: limits

If we have the limit $$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{xy(x-y)}{x-y}}$$ can we simply cancel $(x-y)$ from numerator and denominator and conclude $\frac{0\cdot 0\cdot 1}{1} = 0$?

Comment: How is the function defined for $x=y$?

Comment: Yes, you can cancel $(x-y)$ from the numerator and denominator, so the limit is equal to:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} {xy}=0$$

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I believe it does not matter here, since the question does not talk about the continuity.

Comment: @math137 Yes, but that's not about just value at the point where we compute the limit. Any neighbour contains points with $x=y$, so to say anything about the limit at $(0, 0)$ we need to know the values at such points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed cancel $x-y$. However, we can also work with a more "comfortable" limit of a one variable if we go to polar coordinates:

$x=r\cos\theta$

$y=r\sin\theta$

Then your limit $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ corresponds to $r\rightarrow 0$ and we have

$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^{3}\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}{r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}r^{2}\cos\theta\sin\theta$

Now, the above limit is equal to zero since $\cos\theta\sin\theta$ is bounded for all $\theta$.